# About detemining the time of interview

Tags: job, faculty-application, interview

I have been asked for a faculty position interview. Regarding the time, in their email they have only asked me about my availability for two days without a specific time. I want to know that in my confirmation reply, should I provide a specific time for interview or I just determine the day?

Comment: One should ask them specifically. It may be an all-day (or two-day) process. A one-hour interview for a faculty position seems unlikely.

Comment: I think an accurate answer to this question requires us to know exactly what they've asked. If they've asked "Could you confirm your availability for 1st & 2nd June", the expected answer is probably along the lines of "I'm available all day on the 1st, and any time after 1pm on the 2nd". Once they've collected this information from everyone they'll schedule the interviews accordingly.

Comment: You must ask them. Or read their email very carefully to see whether it is implied. Even if it is implied, emailing them to confirm doesn't cost anything. For what it's worth, I'd guess they're asking you to specify two full days during which you'll be available...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My interpretation would be that they want to know what times you would be free on those two days, perhaps for a one hour interview.

I'm assuming that they've named the days.

If so, give them several options if possible. Send them an email with open times that work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a job you want, either clear your calendar for the two days they are proposing, or propose two days when you are free all day.  It's not clear from your question if they are proposing the days or asking you to propose them.

Comment: They told me that they are in the stage of arranging interviews and mentioned that about my availablity for two days.